# Packet Out-of-order with Open vSwitch running on multi-core?

Tags: networking, openstack, openvswitch

From the document, it seems the latest version of Open vSwitch supports multi-core.

In our OpenStack test environment which uses Open vSwitch on the host, it is observed that the sequence of the packets is changed when they are sent from the same VM to the physical network with the same IP destination. Is this something related to the multi-core processing on the host?

We also tried the similar test with kvm (as guest hypervisor) and use Linux bridge on the host, and the packet sequence was kept not changed.

Could anyone give me some hints on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of OVS's normal forwarding behaviors.
http://openvswitch.org/pipermail/discuss/2012-April/007003.html